# Converting OWL/RDF to OWL/XML format

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, owl-api, protege4

I have an ontology OWL/RDF format that imports several ontologies with the same format (OWL/RDF). So I am looking for any tool to convert my ontology into OWL/XML format. I have tried Protege but did not work either because of the imported ontologies or I did not get it right. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: why should Protege not work? I don't get this. The format of the imported ontologies doesn't matter as long as say are valid OWL files

Comment: I do not know !! how can I do it? I might be doing something wrong. I just loaded the ontology and save it as OWL/XML format. Is there anything else to do?

Comment: the question is, **what** does not work after you saved it as OWL/XML format?

Comment: You mention imports. Protege does not change the imported ontologies when saving changes that you're making to the ontology open in the editor (imported ontologies are read only). So, when you save your ontology in a format, you're saving the current ontology, not the imported ontologies, in that format.